# MySQL order by - one column conditional on another column

Tags: mysql, order-by

In MySQL  I have a table (simplified for this question)

```
CREATE TABLE `projects` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `priority` int(11) DEFAULT '1000000',
  `status` enum('new','in_progress','complete') DEFAULT 'new',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I want to select from the table ordered by priority but with rows where status is 'complete' to come last.

This works:

```
SELECT * FROM projects 
order by 
    case 
        when status='complete' then 999999
        when status!='complete' then priority 
    end ASC
```

but changing the 999999 to (select max(priority)+1 from projects) gives unexpected results, half way down the first page of results rows with status=complete appear.

Also this last method probably causes repeated calculation of the same value.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about...

```
ORDER BY (`status` = 'complete'), `priority`
```

The expression **status = 'complete'** would resolve to 0 for non-complete, and 1 for complete... exactly the order you want... so you'd get all of the non-completed items sorted by priority, followed by all the completed items sorted by priority.

Comment: i have a similar issue, i am trying  ORDER BY (`resolution_id` = 3), `resolution_date` ASC
but no kind of sorting is happening.
i have to sort by resolution_date but on condition that resolution_id=3, want the ordered array for the rows having resolution_id =3, all the other resolution_id's dont matter. can you tell me where am i going wrong.

Comment: @Gunnrryy try `ORDER BY (resolution_id = 3 IS NOT TRUE), resolution_date ASC`

Comment: Thanks buddy, that worked. alternately ORDER BY (`resolution_status_id` = 3) ASC, `resolution_date` ASC did the trick too.. thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [**IF()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function, I converted your `ORDER BY` clause to the following:

```
ORDER BY IF(status='complete',999999,priority)
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Isn't that essentially the same as the `CASE` expression in the question?